# pagination and catalog (php mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am a trying to make a catalog with pagination function (php mysql and jQuery).

I successfully made a pagination page to load the result from mysql database. And I want to add a sidemenu to let the visitor click for show the specific results with pagination effect.

The effect I had made:

```
Left side　　　　right side

Category A　　　item-NO item-name  category 
Category B　　  No.1    Item1     categoryA
Category C　　　No.2    Item2     categoryB
 　　　　　　　　   No.3    Item3     categoryC
 　　　　　　　   　No.4    Item4     categoryA
 　　　　　　　　   No.5    Item5     categoryB
 　　　　　　　　   No.6    Item6     categoryC
 　　　　　　　　   No.7    Item7     categoryA

 　　　　Page 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I want to click the button ( or link ) from left side to show the below effect:

```
Left side　　　　right side

Category A item-NO  item-name    category 
Category B　　　NO.1    Item1     categoryA
Category C　　　No.4    Item4     categoryA
 　　　　　　　　   No.7    Item7     categoryA
 　　　　　　　
          Page 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I tried to make that effect but fail.

This is my code:

```html
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("select * from mytable"); 
$total = mysql_num_rows($sql);

$adjacents  = 1;
$limit = 5; 
$targetpage = "index.php"; 
$total_page = ceil($total/$limit);
$page = $_GET['page'];

if($page){ 
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
}else{
$start = 0;
}

$tpages = ($_GET['tpages']) ? intval($_GET['tpages']) : $total_page; 

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY NO DESC limit $start ,$limit";
$sql_query = mysql_query($sql2);

if($page<=0)  $page  = 1;
if($adjacents<=0) $adjacents = 1;

$reload = $targetpage . "?";
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>My item</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container mtb">
<div align="center">
</div>
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3"><p></p>
         <div class="">
                 <ul class="list-inline">
                     <li><a href="#"><small>Category A<</small></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"><small>Category B</small></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><small>Category C</small></a></li>
                    </ul>
 </div></div>
       
                 <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">total item:：<?php echo  $total ?></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">NO</th>
              <th class="text-center">item name</th>
              <th class="text-center">category</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <?php while($curnm = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query)) { 
  ?>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-center"><?php echo  $curnm['NO'] ?></td>
              <td class="text-center"><?php echo  $curnm['item'] ?></td>
              <td class="text-center"><?php echo  $curnm['category'] ?></td>
            </tr>
             <?php } ?>  
          </tbody>
        </table>
  <hr>
   
   <?php
include("pagination3.php");
echo paginate_three($reload, $page, $tpages, $adjacents);

?>  
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
       </div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried and let us know where you're stuck. I'm not really sure what it is you're asking, since you say _"I successfully made a pagination page to load the result"_.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)